# TextNode or textContent?

Tags: javascript, dom, createtextnode

What's the advantage of creating a TextNode and appending it to an HTML element over setting directly its textContent?

Let's say I have a span.

```js
var span = document.getElementById('my-span');
```

And I want to change its text. What's the advantage of using :

```js
var my_text = document.createTextNode('Hello!');
span.appendChild(my_text);
```

over

`span.textContent = 'hello';`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It 's not really matter of advantage but of proper usage depending on the need.

The fundamental difference is that:

- `createTextNode()` is a method and works just as its name says: it creates an element... then you must do something with it (like in your example, where you append it as a child);
  **so it is useful if you want to have a new element and place it somewhere**
- `textContent` is a property you may get or set, with a unique statement and nothing else;
  **so it is useful when you only want to change the content of an *already existing* element**

Now in the precise case of your question, you said you want to **change** the text of the element...
To be more clear say you have the following HTML element:

```
<span>Original text</span>
```

If you're using your first solution:

```
var my_text = document.createTextNode('Hello!');
span.appendChild(my_text);
```

then it will end with:

```
<span>Original textHello!</span>
```

because you **appended** your `textNode`.

So you should use the second solution.