# Insert a new h3 element before the first paragraph in the body using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to insert a new h3 element having my name before the first paragraph in the HTML only by using javascript. I do not want to edit the HTML file or the CSS file for it.
I have tried this code in the javascript file

```
let h3e = document.createElement("h3");
h3e.textContent("Student Name");
document.body.insertBefore(h3e, document.body.firstChild);
```

But it is not working

```js
let h3e = document.createElement("h3");
h3e.textContent("Student Name");
document.body.insertBefore(h3e, document.body.firstChild);
```

```html
<body>
      <header>
        <h1>Bumblebee</h1>
      </header>

      <main>
        <h2>General description</h2>

        <figure><img src="bee1.jpg" />
          <figcaption>A common bumblebee extending its tongue towards a Heuchera inflorescence.
          </figcaption>
        </figure>

        <p>Bumblebees vary in o about 40 mm longginger beast".</p>

          <h2>Distribution and habitat</h2>

    <p>Test data</p>
</body>
```

Comment: If you look in the dev console you will see an error. The error is that `h3e.textContent` is not a function. You should just assign to it rather than call it. i.e. `h3e.textContent ="Student Name";`.

Comment: I want the "Student Name"to be shown before <p>Bumblebees vary in o about 40 mm longginger beast".</p> tag

Comment: You just need to find the paragraph node using `document.querySelector('p')` and insert before that. The unclosed <main> tag in your example might be causing issue though.

Comment: var h3e = document.createElement("H3");
var t = document.createTextNode("Student Name");
h3e.appendChild(t);
document.body.insertBefore(h3e, document.querySelector("main > p") );                                              query selector isnt working.

Answer (score 1):

To insert after the paragraph you need to call the [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method on the immediate parent Node of the paragraph Node. So its not `document` you want to call it on but the `main` element. Note: in your example the main tag isn't closed. If you took away the main Node then you could use `document.insertBefore` as then document is the immediate parent of the paragraph.

So to do it with your above example, you could do it as shown below. I put in a time delay to show it before and after the element is inserted.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
          <h1>Bumblebee</h1>
        </header>      
        <main>
          <h2>General description</h2>      
          <figure><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a8/Xylocopa_bee1.jpg/300px-Xylocopa_bee1.jpg" />
            <figcaption>A common bumblebee extending its tongue towards a Heuchera inflorescence.
            </figcaption>
          </figure>      
          <p>Bumblebees vary in o about 40 mm longginger beast".</p>      
            <h2>Distribution and habitat</h2>
        </main>
      <p>Test data</p>
  </body>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {
        const h3e = document.createElement("h3");
        h3e.textContent ="Student Name";
        const mainElem = document.querySelector('main');
        const paragraph = mainElem.querySelector("p");
        mainElem.insertBefore(h3e, paragraph);
     }, 1000);
  </script>
</html>
```

You may want to look to the other answer wrt best practice for setting the text in the `h3` node.

Another way to do it that is perhaps more robust is to call `insertBefore` on the parent of the `paragraph` node.

e.g.

```
paragraph.parentNode.insertBefore(h3e, paragraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
h3e.textContent("Student Name");

// Error msg: "Uncaught TypeError: h3e.textContent is not a function",
```

Change to

```
var t = document.createTextNode("Student Name");
h3e.appendChild(t);
```

Or as @Paul Rooney's comment:

```
h3e.textContent ="Student Name";
```

**Full code & demo here:**

```js
var h3e = document.createElement("H3");
var t = document.createTextNode("Student Name");
h3e.appendChild(t);

document.body.insertBefore(h3e, document.body.firstChild);
```

```html
<body>
      <header>
        <h1>Bumblebee</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <h2>General description</h2>
        <figure><img src="bee1.jpg" />
          <figcaption>A common bumblebee extending its tongue towards a Heuchera inflorescence.
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>Bumblebees vary in o about 40 mm longginger beast".</p>
          <h2>Distribution and habitat</h2>
    <p>Test data</p>
</body>
```

---

***Read this thread in more detail:*** [TextNode or textContent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643204/textnode-or-textcontent)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply Do like that

```
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
p.outerHTML = '<h3>Student Name</h3>' + p.outerHTML
```

Comment: tried this      let h3e = document.createElement("H3");
let t = document.createTextNode("Student Name");
h3e.appendChild(t);

let ptag = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
document.body.insertBefore(h3e, ptag);

Comment: Just copy above code and try in your browser conole